# Windows Server 2003: Able to log in as domain user, but unable to set permissions for domain users

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, domain, active-directory

I have a very simple network that has one domain controller (Win Server 2003) and one other computer that is part of the domain (also Win Server 2003). This other computer will allow me to log in as a domain user, but when I am trying to set permissions on some shared folders, it won't let me set permissions for domain users; only local users.

I have tried specifying the domain of the user like NETWORKDOMAIN\domainuser and domainuser@networkdomain.mydomain.com, but neither work. When I click on the Locations button, the name of the domain is left out and it only shows me the name of the local computer.

I have been able to do this before; I can't think of anything that's different. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a better way of going about things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check you DNS settings and make sure that the member server can connect to the domain controller. You say you can login with a domain account, but this could be using cached credentials if it is unable to contact the DC, however when you try to change permissions, it needs to be able to contact a DC.

Comment: I looked at the event log and noticed that the DNS service had encountered an error and stopped functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Can you logon to that member server using domain admin account and view an c$ folder on domain controller?